# Checking for matches and comparing multiple lists, using Excel

Tags: excel

I am an noob when it comes to excel and would really appreciate some help with this task. I would like to compare these three separate lists of course numbers/names and check if a given course number has the same course name associated in each list.

Here is an image of what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

As you can see, course 2352 is associated with "Dance choreography and production" in the first two lists, so that's returned in a different check list with the an "OK". However, course 2354 is "Folk/ethnic dance" in the first list, and 'Admin program evaluation/research' in the third list, so that is not ok. Similarly, 0107 is associated with different names across the lists.

Any ideas for how I could easily achieve this kind of check in excel? Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option:

```
=IF((SUMPRODUCT((L1=$A$1:$I$10)-(M1=$A$1:$I$10)))<>0,"Not OK","OK")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use three COUNTIFS that check if any do not match:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,L2,B:B,"<>"&M2)+COUNTIFS(E:E,L2,F:F,"<>"&M2)+COUNTIFS(H:H,L2,I:I,"<>"&M2)>0,"Not OK","OK")
```